# Python : why numba takes more time?

Tags: python, numba

I am using `list comprehension` to gather data from `list` of `tuples`. Code below:

```
data = [result[0] for result in results] #results is a list of tuples and i take first element from each tuple.
```

This works and all good.

Recently i came across `numba` module which will increase speed of loop execution ?

**So i tried this to test timing:**

```
import numba
from numba import literal_unroll
from datetime import datetime
import logging

numba_logger = logging.getLogger('numba')
numba_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

@numba.jit(nopython=True)
def loop_faster(results):
    for result in literal_unroll(results):
        print(result)
    
tuples = (1.1, "Hello", 1, "World", "Tuple-1")

print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

loop_faster(tuples)

print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

for result in tuples:
        print(result)

print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

i refereed this link for `literal_unroll` : https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html

However it seems for loop performs way better than `numba` method.

**Results for above program :**

```
2021-03-04 10:51:36.385
1.1
Hello
1
World
Tuple-1
2021-03-04 10:51:47.234
1.1
Hello
1
World
Tuple-1
2021-03-04 10:51:47.236
```

Why is this behavior ? numba took almost over 10-Seconds

For my case to form a list out of tuple's nth element , how can i implement using `numba` module ?

Comment: Have you tried with very long tuples? The speed gain should be appreciable when dealing with long arrays, a simple 4 items tuple won't cut it.

Comment: Reason is simple. You measured total running time of function. It includes first time compilation time, which is very long usually. Try passing `cache = True` inside `@numba.jit` decorator and run program twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is very simple, on first run of function a lot of time is spend in compiling Ayour code into C++ code and machine code, which is doing numba's JIT.

So you have to add param `cache = True` to you `@numba.jit` decorator to pre-cache compiled version. Also you have to call one time run before measuring time to ensure compilation. Also you have to run more loops iterations to mesure time more precisely, just 10 milliseconds run is not enough.

Following code does three things mentioned above. You can see that numba gives `5.5x` times speedup.

Also I modified your code for a bit different logic, because printing logic will not measure time correctly. Numba is meant for very computational heavy code, not for printing to console. So I just created random integers array and computed this array +1. This is enough as an example code for you to see that Numba runs much faster.

[Try it online!](https://repl.it/@moytrage/StackOverflow66473619#main.py)

```
import numba, logging, random
from datetime import datetime

numba_logger = logging.getLogger('numba')
numba_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

@numba.njit(cache = True)
def loop_faster(results, n):
    for i in range(n):
        res = []
        for result in numba.literal_unroll(results):
            res.append(result + 1)
    
t = tuple(random.randrange(1 << 20) for i in range(100))

loop_faster(t, 10) # pre-compile numba

print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

loop_faster(t, 1 << 16)

print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])

for i in range(1 << 16):
    res = []
    for result in t:
        res.append(result + 1)

print(datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3])
```

Output:

```
2021-03-04 12:18:04.491
2021-03-04 12:18:04.840
2021-03-04 12:18:06.774
```